# What is the difference between rf$importance and importance(rf) in the package randomForest in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest

I am building a hybrid filter-wrapper model for feature selection. As a filter I select the 100 most important variables based on the output of a Random Forest. However, I noticed that with 2 different ways of calling the importance, the returned values for Mean Decrease Accuracy are different:

[image]

So my question is what is the difference between using $importance and importance()?

Comment: Hi there and welcome. What does the documentation say? E.g. try `?importance()`, `?randomForest()`, [Rdoc: randomForest](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/randomForest) and [Rdoc: randomForest::importance()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/importance). – *Reviewer*

Answer (score 2):

By default, `importance()` scales the results by the standard error of the measure (see the help page). If you specify `importance` with the parameter `scale=FALSE`, you will get identical results as from `my_forest$importance`.

The results will not be identical after scaling, but fairly similar as to which variables are most important and the order at the far end. Here is an example from my work:

[image]